# can a media query load an external html page, that will then load the css link from that?

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

Unfortunately I miss-read articles on how to make media queries to enable a mobile version of my website. So instead of just making a customised css page, I made a new html structure for the mobile version as well.

My question is - Can I input a media query into my main html page that can link my 'mobile version' html page... that then will load my 'mobile version' css stylesheet? (poor explanation, sorry) I know it's such a stupid and slow way of doing it and I will research and do it the a proper way, but for now can I make this work?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can't do that with **CSS**, **CSS** is only for styling. However, you can test with **javascript** or some _server-side language_ if the user is viewing the page via _mobile_ then `redirect` them to the `mobile` version of your webpage (example, `www.myWebSite.com/mobile/`).

Comment: Thanks, yeah that makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 1):

You can call a specific css file in your html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
```

Comment: Yeh thanks, that's what I did however I wanted some images to show on a desktop but not on mobile so I needed another html file which didn't include certain images, the same with a few lists as well.

Answer (score 0):

make a mediaquery in an external css file and put a class and a img tag after eachother with a display:none